# Ethereum Hard Fork and blockchain

Tags: hardforks

If i do Ethereum Hard Fork to build DApp - Does it need to be on Ethereum or could be a separate blockchain system? If we build a separate blockchain system, what is the advantage of hard-forking from ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

In order to take advantage of the Ethereum ecosystem, you must build your DApp on the main chain. If you were to fork Ethereum, your chain would not have the implicit security and users that the main chain does. Your DApp has to be on the main chain for anyone to (logically) interact with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I understand this right, if I do a hard fork, then I land up creating a different blockchain system /platform that becomes a private network. Is my understanding correct? another related question: this link talks about creating a private network for the purpose of testing: https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html - Does this mean this is possible without doing a hard fork? and then move everything back to the main chain after testing?

Comment: Exactly. Take a look at [these](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network) docs to learn more.